# NSURLRequest with cachePolicy ReloadIgnoringCacheData return stale data

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, tvos, apple-tv

I have an usecase where i need to poll a rest api for authentication on Apple TV. I get stale response JSON response for 90-120 sec after which i am getting proper JSON response. 
Below is my code

```
static func getFileNoCache(url:NSURL?, completionHandler:(NSData?, String?)->Void) {
    if let fileUrl = url {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: fileUrl, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
        let dataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,
            completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                if let err = error {
                    // failed !
                    print("!! Error - Download Failed \n\t\(fileUrl) reason:\(err.localizedDescription)")
                    completionHandler (nil, err.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                if let statusCode = (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    if statusCode == 200 {
                        completionHandler(data, nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        completionHandler (nil, "Message")
                    }
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler (nil, "Invalid response")
                    print("!! Error - Downloading EPG Config")
                }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

I m really clueless whats going wrong

Comment: This could be due to server side caching or using a proxy cdn such as cloudflare, have you tried making the requests seperately using something like postman?

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of things, from proxies to server-side caching to bugs in the shared session's behavior.

Try disabling the cache entirely by using your own session configuration, setting its *URLCache* property to *nil*, then creating a session based on that configuration.

If that doesn't work, then the caching is not in your machine, and your best bet is to add a cache-buster to the URL (e.g. *&ignoredParameter=monotonically_increasing_number*).